# Unity: How to transfer time script to 24 hours and not decimals

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, time, decimal

so I've found a script online for Unity that is a Day and Night cycle however it works in decimals, 0.1 to 1, however I want it to be 1 to 24.

The code I am using is below, I have tried fiddling around with the decimal values however I can't get it correct.

```
    using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class DayNightCycle : MonoBehaviour {

    public Light sun;
    public float secondsInFullDay = 120f;
    [Range(0,24)]
    public float currentTimeOfDay = 0;
    [HideInInspector]
    public float timeMultiplier = 1f;

    float sunInitialIntensity;

    void Start() {
        sunInitialIntensity = sun.intensity;
    }

    void Update() {
        UpdateSun();

        currentTimeOfDay += (Time.deltaTime / secondsInFullDay) * timeMultiplier;

        if (currentTimeOfDay >= 24) {
            currentTimeOfDay = 0;
        }
    }

    void UpdateSun() {
        sun.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler((currentTimeOfDay * 360f) - 90, 170, 0);

        float intensityMultiplier = 1;
        if (currentTimeOfDay <= 0.23f || currentTimeOfDay >= 0.75f) {
            intensityMultiplier = 0;
        }
        else if (currentTimeOfDay <= 0.25f) {
            intensityMultiplier = Mathf.Clamp01((currentTimeOfDay - 0.23f) * (1 / 0.02f));
        }
        else if (currentTimeOfDay >= 0.73f) {
            intensityMultiplier = Mathf.Clamp01(1 - ((currentTimeOfDay - 0.73f) * (1 / 0.02f)));
        }

        sun.intensity = sunInitialIntensity * intensityMultiplier;
    }
}
```

The result I want is for the day and night cycle to work from 1 to 24 and not 0 to 1, so that there's 24 hours in the game, and that it's easier to modify when using a sleep script I've made.

Comment: `time = time * 23 + 1` ? Explanation: `time * 23` convert your number from interval [0;1] to [0; 23] then add 1 so you have an interval [1; 24]

Comment: I think the same a Ludovic,  you should convert your 0,1 to 0,23 just multiplying. I think the slider value was just a normalizaed position value.

Comment: @LudovicFeltz updated code, accidentally put wrong one in

Comment: A DataTime object has a integer that is the number of days from 1/1/01 and a fraction which is fractional part of 24 hours.  So the code posted is using .25 (time from midnight to 6:00AM) and .75 (time from 6:00PM to midnight).

Comment: I posted an answer with the method to compute your value. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

To convert a value between `0` and `1` (interval `[0, 1]`) you just have to multiply by the size of your new interval then add the first value of your interval.

So if you have a variable `value` and want an interval: `[MIN, MAX]` the calculation is the following:

```
var newValue = (value * (MAX - MIN)) + MIN;
```

In you case you want the interval `[1, 24]` so it is:

```
var newValue = (value * 23) + 1;
```

Simple maths, hope it helps.